# Why is there a Syntax error in my dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, syntax

```
message = input(">")
words = message.split(' ')

emojis = {
    ":)": ""
    ":(": ""
}

output = ""
for word in words:
    output += emojis.get(word,word) + ' '

print(output)
```

This is the syntax error. I do not understand why the colon is incorrect.

```
line 6
    ":(": ""
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a comma to separate the elements of your dict:

```
emojis = {
    ":)": "", # <- added comma here
    ":(": ""
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I totally forgot.

Comment: You're welcome. And good luck with your project. 